# "The Transaction is invalid ...." PayPal when I send user for approval

Tags: php, paypal, wordpress

I am really in trouble from couple of hours, tried many ways but still no luck. I have integrated PayPal in my wordpress theme using Paypal Framework Wordpress plugin. The Sandbox settings are working fine. I got Success on SetExpressCheckout with Token, When I send user to PayPal for approval and payment using https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?TOKEN=EC-2FY692500K5578627&cmd=_express-checkout it gives me error...

`This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.`

Please help, what can I do to make it work... I am really worried... :(

**UPDATED**

I am sending following params for `SetExpressCheckout`

```
$ppParams = array(
        'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
        'RETURNURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=paypal_handler&step=commit&user_id=' . $user_id),
        'CANCELURL' => home_url(),
        'AMT' => $price,
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $price,
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $price,
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0' => 'Digital',
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'Prod Name',
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => 1,
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => $price,
        'DESC' => 'description',
        'FIRSTNAME' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'LASTNAME' => $_POST['last_name'],
        'EMAIL' => $email
    );

    $response = hashCall($ppParams);
```

I am using following https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted for cross checking and implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh! found the solution... it was nothing just use lower-case letters for `TOKEN`... in `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?token=EC-2FY692500K5578627&cmd=_express-checkout`